# Locate LINK using Selenium - Python

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to get the ADDRESS in a webpage, but I don't know the full address, just a part, such as ( https://activationrequest.).
I am trying to use the code below, but is not working.

`browser.find_element_by_link_text('https://activationrequest')`

`System.out.println("Title of page is: " + driver.getTitle());`

Please, anyone can help me?

Comment: You can try using driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('yoururl'). Also you have a Java code in a Python file. print("Title of page is: "+driver.title)

Comment: Can you also include the html element in question.

Comment: Add at least the part of html you are looking at